# How do I compress a directory on a Unix web server and email it on a sheduled basis?

Tags: email, backup, unix, scheduled-tasks, crontab

After hearing about various high profile website creators getting stiffed recently after hardware failures on their servers I would like to implement a backup strategy on my websites.

I have cPanel available to me but there is no facilty for me to schedule backups and have them emailed to me. There is the facility to "crontab" but I am not an experienced Unix user so don't know how to use that.

What I would like to be able to do is create a backup of my entire home directory, compressing it at the same time and then sending an email notifying me such a backup has been done and I can download and archive.

Please can somebody provide me with any pointers on how I would do such a thing?

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: The best solution may be to use the 'crontab' facility. It's worth learning about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start you off the commands you want to learn how to use; `tar`, `mail` and basic shell scripting.

### The Shell Script

A really quick and dirty example of how to do this would be the following:

```
#! /bin/sh

# The following command creates a GZIP'd version of your folder. -c = create
# -z = use gzip, -f = file name of backup file
# You can use j instead of z to use bzip2. It's slightly slower but compresses
# more. Beware that images, videos and such do not compress well.
cd /PATH/NOT/IN/HOME/FOLDER; tar czf backup.tgz /PATH/TO/HOME/FOLDER

# If you only have access to your home folder you can modify the command to
# look like so, regular expressions are your friend here.
tar czf backup.tgz FOLDER1 FOLDER2 FILE3

# The mail program may be disabled and uses the local SMTP server so depending
# on your mail setup it may never even get to your inbox because it is flagged
# as unverified mail (Spam). For example, Gmail or a domain not hosted on that
# same server will almost most certainly not work. If this fails to work you
# can create a PHP or Python script that actually allows you to set the SMTP
# server. An alternative is to have this script echo some output and have cron
# send the output to you instead. It's dependent on your setup.
# -s Subject
# 
mail -s "Backup Done!" "youremailaddress@wherever.com"
```

Set the script to executable (`chmod 755 nameOfScript.sh`) and make note of where you've saved it on your

### Getting Crontab to run the Shell Script

To set up your crontab from the command line enter `crontab -e` to edit your crontab file. The layout of the file is as below:

```
*     *   *   *    *  command to be executed
-     -    -    -    -
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |     +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Source of Diagram: [Admin's Choice](http://www.adminschoice.com/docs/crontab.htm#Commands)

In this case, adding a line such as:

```
33  0 * * *    /PATH/TO/HOME/FOLDER/nameOfScript.sh
```

will run the script every day at 0:33 / 12:33 AM.

If you want to find out more check out the man pages for `tar`, `mail` and `crontab`. They're indispensable when dealing with UNIX administration in any form. With `uuencode` you could even email the whole site to yourself if it was small enough.